# Answer getting printed in console but not while executing the program file (Python)

Tags: python

I am executing the following python code

```
a=1
b=2
"bigger" if a>b else "smaller"
```

1) When I execute in console window of Python, I get the result as -> 'smaller'
2) When I put it in a python file and execute, I do not get any results (neither errors)
Can you provide some hints?

Answer (score 4):

In a Python console, it automatically prints what the code returns. When you run a file, you must print the result yourself. To display the code when running a file, you must use `print(<code>)`. Try this for the file:

```
a=1
b=2
print("bigger" if a>b else "smaller")
```